# Azure get storage exception while upload file

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

while i upload file from the server to the Azure i get bellow error, I find something the error because of time, but i confused Should i change time to which timezone ?

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:
>   Server fai led to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: Please check the clock on the server. More than likely the clock on the server is off my more than 15-20 minutes. It doesn’t matter what time zone the server is in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value

Answer (score 0):

You should use UTC time in your request and your signature. If you still working on it , pls let me know your programming language and I'll provide you with a demo for uploading files to Azure storage blob.

Comment: I'm using asp.net core webapi / c#