# Authentication Failure when Accessing Azure Blob Storage through Connection String

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, nix, azure-authentication

We got error of Authentication fail, when we try to create an azure blob client from connection string, using python v12 sdk with Azure Blob Storage v12.5.0, and Azure core 1.8.2.

I used
azure-storate-blob == 12.5.0
azure-core == 1.8.2

I tried to access my blob storage account using connection string with Python v12 SDK and received the error above. The environment I'm running in is python venv in NixShell.

The code for calling the blob_upload is as following:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=<>,credential=<>)    
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name,
        blob=file)
```

I printed out blob_client, and it looks normal. But the next line of upload_blob gives error.

```
with open(os.path.join(root,file), "rb") as data:
                    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

The error message is as follows

```
    File "<local_address>/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_upload_helpers.py", in upload_block_blob
    return client.upload(
  File "<local_address>/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_block_blob_operations.py", in upload
    raise models.StorageErrorException(response, self._deserialize)
azure.storage.blob._generated.models._models_py3.StorageErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.'
```

So I printed out the http put request to azure blob storage, and get the response value of [403]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can work the following code well with the version the same as yours.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
blob=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="your connect string in Access Keys")
with open("./SampleSource.txt", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

Please check your connect-string, and check your PC's time.

There is a similar issue about the error: [AzureStorage Blob Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value)

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried with this code, and get the same error:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://pamelastorage123.blob.core.windows.net/",credential=token_credential)    
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="pamelac", blob="New Text Document.txt")

with open("D:/demo/python/New Text Document.txt", "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

[image]

Then I use `AzureCliCredential()` instead of `DefaultAzureCredential()`. I authenticate via the Azure CLI with `az login`. And it works.

[image]

If you use environment credential, you need to set the variables. Anyway, I recommend you to use the **specific credentials** instead `DefaultAzureCredential`.

For more details about Azure Identity, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity#credential-classes).

Comment: The question arise when I try to upload file to the blob storage :
which by calling  blob_client.upload_blob(data)

File "/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/response_handlers.py", line 147, in process_storage_error
    raise error

Comment: Hi, @AliciaYang! Could you add your code to the issue?

Comment: I add the sample about uploading a blob in my reply. Please share the details of your error.

Comment: Hi Pamela, Thank you for the reply, due to the words limit in reply channel, I add the code to the post

Comment: Also in my nix virtual environment, the time is showing to almost the same as the current time with micro second different. But it has the unit of DST instead of EDT, do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: Just a little difference in time doesn't matter. I reproduce the error with DefaultAzureCredential(), please see my UPDATE.