# Microsoft Azure - failed to create table: StorageError: Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have a node.js with AngularJs Web application. And in production environment it is failing. In App logs  it shows as

```
/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/connect-azuretables/lib/connect-azuretables.js:86
 throw ('failed to create table: ' + error);

"failed to create table: Storage Error: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
```

I am new to Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication Failure when Accessing Azure Blob Storage through Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344806/authentication-failure-when-accessing-azure-blob-storage-through-connection-stri)

Comment: You can refer to similar issues [Azure Blob: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678093/azure-blob-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value), [Azure Blob Storage fails to authenticate: "Make sure the value of Authorization header..."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/334786/azure-blob-storage-fails-to-authenticate-34make-su.html) and [Error with 'Server failed to authenticate the request'](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/330)

Answer (score 0):

Please check few points:

1. The issue maybe due to time zone difference. Please set the proper time and timezone  of your pc and execute.
2. Also please check if  accesss key is correct .Note that the key is case sensitive and make sure you have not included white spaces.Also check if SAS has expired.SAS url may not require "?" in url .Please check if "?" is present in sas url creation.
3. If not generate the keys or connection string again and try to use them.
4. Please make sure you have Storage Blob Data Contributor role in azure. Navigate to Storage account -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add role assignment to do the same
5. Check if any firewall is blocking the request .
6. Other wise see if it is the issue with  azure node js sdk version.