# Azure python sdk authentication using SAS url

Tags: azure-python-sdk

I'm using this code to try to check successful connectivity to azure using python sdk

```py
tgt_container_url = f'https://{storage_acct_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}'
sas_url = f"{tgt_container_url}?{sas_key}"
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)
snapshot_blob = blob_client.create_snapshot()
print(snapshot_blob.get('snapshot'))
```

I receive the below error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError:
Operation returned an invalid status 'Server failed to authenticate the request.
Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.'
```

Any suggestions would be great. thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication Failure when Accessing Azure Blob Storage through Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344806/authentication-failure-when-accessing-azure-blob-storage-through-connection-stri)

Comment: [Azure Blob: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678093/azure-blob-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value) and [Azure Blob Storage fails to authenticate: "Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/334786/azure-blob-storage-fails-to-authenticate-34make-su.html)

Comment: Thanks Markus and Deep. I was unable to get it working but having received the account access key, i hope it will be easier through the creation of connection string  `f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={storage_acct_name};AccountKey={storage_acct_key}"`