# Azure Data Factory ODATA to Snowflake Database

Tags: odata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

New to Azure data factory.
We have .CSV file, we need to use ODATA and load to Snowflake table.
I created 2 datasets, 2 linked services and 1 1 pipeline.

I loaded the data to Snowflake table with screenshot attached

The issue which iam facing now is, one comment column is there. DATE format
"DD/MM/YYYY."

The date column is coming as NULL in output.

When i view the data in source, the date value able to see, but in Derived expression builder, the date value is NULL
The flow is
Odata - > Blob Storage (JSON)
JSON -> Derived -> Target

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Its might be a cause of the key for the account is to check on and the Date time of your local machine with respect to GMT. Often the firewalls might cause the same issue . Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Networking -> Check Allow Access From (All Networks / Selected Networks)- which means it has been firewall enabled instead needed to be whitelisted or if you are using a connection string to access via SAS token rather than a Actual key? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Iam trying to load now from ODATA(.csv file) to Blob storage

When I am trying to load the data from ODATA to azure blob storage , I am getting single value (comment's data) splitting to two.

Column data/value
"Shop all day.
Steel cutting and plasma."

On the blob storage output it is coming in multiple lines.
Can you please let me know how I can write the data in a single line instead of multiple lines ?

Thanks

Comment: May I know which type of activity you have been using while copying the data and could you please help with a screenshot?