# Azure Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

`enter code here`I am trying to download the file stored in azure blob using javascript and getting this error.

Here is my code

```
function getUrlOfAttachmentFileFromBlob(new_fileurl,new_fileName) {
  var fileHyperlink = '';
  var blobUri = 'https://' + 'Storage_Account_Name' + '.blob.core.windows.net';
  var containerName = 'trial';
  var sas_token = 'sastoken' ;
    
  var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sas_token);
  //.withFilter(new AzureStorage.Blob.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());

  var downloadLink = blobService.getUrl(new_fileName, new_fileurl.replace('/'+containerName+'/',''), sas_token);

  if (downloadLink != null)
  {
      alert("Link " + downloadLink);
      downloadURI(downloadLink, new_fileName);
  }
}
```

I am not generating shared signature and sas token here. I am directly assigning the sas token to the variable.

When I try to open the link in browser I am getting this error

```
AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:504f2ef5-f01e-0021-0e02-74e194000000
Time:2021-07-08T14:09:47.9951927Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>sp is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

I am not passing any headers in my code.

What i am missing here?

> SAS Token =
> ?sp=r&st=2021-07-08T12:19:08Z&se=2021-07-08T20:19:08Z&spr=https&sv=2020-02-10&sr=c&
>
> Without sig part.

This is what I am getting from geturl function =

> ?%3Fsv=2020-02-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacuptfx&se=2021-07-11T12%3A30%3A23Z&st=2021-06-11T04%3A30%3A23Z&spr=https%2chttp&

I think I am not getting correct url from this function, so i replaced that line with  this

```
const downloadLink = blobUri +'/' + containerName + '/' + new_fileName + sas_token;
```

But still not able to download the file. But not getting authentication error.

Thank you...

Comment: Did you make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly, including the signature?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - The authorization header part in the error details is kind of misleading :). The issue is with SAS token only. I have provided that as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AzureStorage Blob Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this error is because your SAS token is not valid. If you look closely at the error message you will see the following:

```
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>sp is mandatory. Cannot be empty</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

Essentially your SAS token is missing `signed permissions (sp)` parameter. Please check your SAS token and make sure that it is correctly formed.

Comment: I am providing correct sas token. But I am not getting proper sas token from this function, which is in Azure blob storage library.                                                              
 var downloadLink = blobService.getUrl(new_fileName, new_fileurl.replace('/'+containerName+'/',''), sas_token);

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the SAS token? You can obfuscate the `sig` portion of your SAS token.

Comment: Also share the downloadLink.

Comment: I have edited my question including sas token. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. There’s definitely an issue with your getUrl function. Is this a custom function you wrote? I don’t recall this function in the SDK.

Comment: Its not a custom function. I referred this link https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html.  Using this library

Comment: @amruthavarshini - you are using a legacy Javascript library `Storage SDK v2 for JavaScript`. I recommend that you use `Storage SDK v12 for JavaScript` https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/main/sdk/storage

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the related issues on shared access signature (SAS)
Allowed resource types by clicking
Service

Container

Object
and finally generate new token works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using the incorrect PowerShell cmdlet to create the SAS token in the first place, hence why I was always getting Authorization error in my AZCOPY command

I was using: `New-AzStorageFileSASToken` cmdlet

Changing to use: `New-AzStorageShareSASToken` cmdlet resolved the auth issues for me.

Original error:

```
Description=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature
```