# Azure Databricks : Error writing to DBFS - java.io.IOException: Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: azure-databricks

I have a 3.25 day job that failed when writing the dataframe to DBFS.
Update:  I have had a 2nd long job (also 3+ days) fail in the same manner.  I can use this cluster for smaller jobs with no issues, it looks like only long jobs are impacted.

```
java.io.IOException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. Please see the cause for further information.
    at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.initIOException(Utility.java:769)
```

It looks like Spark wasn't able to authenticate to the storage account Azure Databricks uses for the DBFS root.   My notebook writes the dataframe to DBFS and then uploads the results to ADLS as a later stage.  The run is failing before it gets to that part (as shown in the stack trace and lack of trace message indicating it got to the upload stage)

I can run shorter jobs just fine, so it's not a fundamental problem.

Does anyone know what happened here and how I can make this more robust?  I'd like to avoid losing all data from the run next time.

Here is the error trace:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-920141663601998> in <module>
    121 app_details_json_dataframe2.show( truncate=100 )
    122 
--> 123 app_details_json_dataframe2.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").option("header","true").option("compression", "gzip").json(path="/data/Directory")
    124 
    125 for f in dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/data/Directory/"):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in json(self, path, mode, compression, dateFormat, timestampFormat, lineSep, encoding, ignoreNullFields)
    844             compression=compression, dateFormat=dateFormat, timestampFormat=timestampFormat,
    845             lineSep=lineSep, encoding=encoding, ignoreNullFields=ignoreNullFields)
--> 846         self._jwrite.json(path)
    847 
    848     def parquet(self, path, mode=None, partitionBy=None, compression=None):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1085.json.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:603)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:874)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 27.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 27.0 (TID 58) (10.139.64.4 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$20(FileFormatWriter.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:125)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:826)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1670)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:829)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:684)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. Please see the cause for further information.
    at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.initIOException(Utility.java:769)
    at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStreamInternal.writeBlock(BlobOutputStreamInternal.java:475)
    at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStreamInternal.access$000(BlobOutputStreamInternal.java:47)
    at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStreamInternal$1.call(BlobOutputStreamInternal.java:419)
    at hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStreamInternal$1.call(BlobOutputStreamInternal.java:416)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Self-suppression not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error - Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value
> of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> Please see the cause for further information.

This error can be caused for a number of reasons. I am listing them below.

Please check and make changes according to your use case.

**1.**  If you have metadata for the file, metadata should not contain special characters or whitespace starting of the value and end of the value.

**2.**  Check if there is any issue with shared access signature (SAS).

**3.**  Check the timezone of your computer.

Also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value)

Comment: Thanks Abhishek.
1. I don't have metadata for the file and it works on a smaller set of data in any case.
2. Azure Databricks manages the DBFS connection to it's managed blob storage - I don't see that I have any control over it.  If there is a setting I should be changing, please point me in the right direction.