# Why I'm getting "Make sure Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature" issue while connecting to ADLS using SAS URI?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, sas-token

I have a SAS URI (read, list) for an ADLS hosted in another resource group. While I try to connect to that ADLS using the SAS URI, I get successful connection but unable to copy or browse files.

**Databricks Error:**
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.&#34

**ADF Error suggestion list:**

1. Grant service principal or managed identity appropriate permissions to do copy.
2. It's possible because some IP address ranges of Azure Data Factory are not allowed by your Azure Storage firewall settings.
3. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.StorageExtendedMessage=Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

What is the possible reason and how to resolve it?

The same SAS URI works with Azure Storage Explorer hosted in a VM and I am able to copy files. So, the key is not expired.

Comment: where you are connecting ADLS In databricks or ADF?

Comment: I have tried in both ADLS & ADF, it's the same issue. Main requirement is to use ADF to copy files from that External ADLS.

Comment: both are under same subscription?

Comment: ADF and Databricks are in same subscription but ADLS is in different subscription.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the possible reason and how to resolve it?

Found some possible reasons causing the error:

- The SAS token you are using for a connection is incorrect/expired.
- The time zone difference in your pc time and time generated while creating SAS token.
- Firewall restrictions on ADLS (Whitelist your ADF IP and Client IP).

As you said Main requirement is to use ADF to copy files from that External ADLS. I tried it in my environment and get it done successfully.

check if you are missing anything:

- Generate SAS token with permission you want and copy it as below
  [image]
  [image]
- Pass this SAS token in authentication
  [image]
- Successfully able to bowse the files.
  [image]

Also, refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492790/azurestorage-blob-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-make-sure-the-value) with similar issue.